# Select ID and Class, then toggle element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to toggle the class of an element, and firing a function, dependent on wether the curent class is on/off.

```
  $("#menu-item-485.current-menu-item").click(function(){
           alert('I am function A');
    $("#eduplugin_personal_wiki_widget-2").toggle(1000);
    $("#menu-item-485").toggleClass('current-menu-item not-current-menu-item');
  });
  $("#menu-item-485.not-current-menu-item").click(function(){
          alert('I am function B');
    $("#eduplugin_personal_wiki_widget-2").toggle(1000);
    $("#menu-item-485").toggleClass('current-menu-item not-current-menu-item');
  });
```

When I load the page, the code works fine, and fires alert function A (case: on) and alert function B (case: off). But if I then click the element again, it fires the same function again: I.e. if the initial state is ID=menu-item-485 and class=current-menu-item, it fires alert function A, even if I toggle it.

I would like for one click to be function A, two clicks function A then B, etc.

All best
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the classes that you are removing to the other element. You should be using toggleClass with only one class `current-menu-item`.

There's no need to add a class `not-curren-menu-item`, it would be much better if you just had `current-menu-item` and by omission it would mean that it's not the current item.

Try this out and let me know, I haven't actually tried it though:

```
$("#menu-item-485").click(function () {
   if($(this).hasClass("current-menu-item")) {
      alert('I am function A');
   }
   else {
      alert('I am function B');
   }
   $("#eduplugin_personal_wiki_widget-2").toggle(1000);
   $(this).toggleClass('current-menu-item');
});
```

Comment: This is how you select elements without a class `#menu-item-485:not(.current-menu-item)`

Comment: It produces the exact same result:
`code`<li id="menu-item-485" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-icon menu-item-485 current-menu-item"><a href="#" ...`code`

When clicking the element I get alert function A

It then changes to:
`code`<li id="menu-item-485" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-icon menu-item-485"><a href="#" ...

And produces alert function A.

Comment: I changed the code to:

      $("#menu-item-485.current-menu-item").click(function(){
        alert('I am function A');
      $("#menu-item-485:not(.current-menu-item)").click(function(){
       alert('I am function B');

Comment: Ok, I see you're struggling with it, let me write what I believe the solution to be, I'll edit my answer when it's done

Comment: That worked perfectly!
Any idea why my trigger or the 'not' solution didn't work?

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Let me check, I'll copy the code to VS Code and try out your solutions

Comment: Ok, I see what happens. I'm no expert with jQuery, but I'm pretty sure that the events are attached once the page is loaded and then, even though the requisites are not met anymore, the same element keeps firing the same event. That's why is better to attach one event with all the logic and let the function inside the event determine what should be done in each case. Did I make myself clear?

Comment: I get that, and will keep that in mind. I am sure that information will come in handy down the road :-)
Thanks ever so much for your time.